# Basic question about backing beans for Composite Components

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, composite-component

I can't find any guidance on this question.  I am writing a composite component that needs its own backing bean because it interacts with a data base.

The new component also needs to be able to set a value in some other backing bean as the result of some user action.

To do this, the question is do I have to write a @FacesComponent java class or a regular @Model/@Named (I use CDI annotations) type of bean?   If you can use either, what is the advantage of one or the other?

Secondary question: will I be able to use CDI @Inject into a @FacesComponent to get my DAOs and such?

Update:  I discovered that I can access cc.attr objects with the following code in a regular backing bean:

```
  FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  Object obj = fc.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(fc, 
            "#{cc.attrs.model.location}", Location.class);
```

So this allows me to obtain attributes.  I haven't found out how I can write them yet.

So it seems that the only real reason to do a @FacesComponent is if you want to write rendering code that will output something the normal Facelets tags won't render.   Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think BalusC responded to this basic question in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161875/how-does-a-composite-component-set-a-property-in-its-clients-backing-bean).

The main advantage is the ability of a @FacesComponent to access attributes that a UIComponent normally has access to, rather than trying to tie in with EL expressions executed in the bean.