# How does a composite component set a property in it's client's backing bean?

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I have a composite component with an interface that contains this:

```
<cc:attribute name="model"
                  shortDescription="Bean that contains Location" >
        <cc:attribute name="location" type="pkg.Location"
                      required="true" />
    </cc:attribute>
</cc:interface>
```

So I can access the *Location* object in the markup with **#{cc.attrs.model.location}**.

I also access that object from the backing bean of the composite component like this:

```
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Object obj = fc.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(fc, 
            "#{cc.attrs.model.location}", Location.class);
```

So now my composite component has done its work -- how do I call the setter method on the model from the backing bean?  (i.e. **model.setLocation(someValue)** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`ValueExpression#setValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html#setValue%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.Object%29).

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
ValueExpression valueExpression = facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
    .createValueExpression(elContext, "#{cc.attrs.model.location}", Location.class);

valueExpression.setValue(elContext, newLocation);
```

The [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) by the way calls [`ValueExpression#getValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html#getValue%28javax.el.ELContext%29) under the covers, exactly as described by its [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) (if you have ever read it...)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, are you aware about the possibility to create backing `UIComponent` class for the composite component? I bet that this is much easier than fiddling with `ValueExpression`s this way. You could then just use the inherited `getAttributes()` method to get the `model`.

```
Model model = (Model) getAttributes().get("model);
// ...
```

You can find an example in our [composite component wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info).

Comment: You are talking about using the @FacesComponent anotation, right?  I had posted another question on this topic with a composite-component tag and I guess this answers that question.

Comment: Yes, that's right. See also the linked wiki. I haven't seen your other question. Pay attention to proper tagging. Folks here usually browse by (interesting) tags.

Answer (score 1):

what about the attribute "default"  ? It seam that it is not implemented when using the backing component implementation.

xhtml  :

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="test" 
                         type="java.lang.Boolean" 
                         default="#{false}"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation >
    TEST : #{cc.attrs.test}
</composite:implementation >
```

Java backing implementation :

```
 testValue = (Boolean) getAttributes().get("test");
```

if the test attribute is set in the main xhtml no problem : both xhtml and java backing have the same value. But when not set the default value is only on xhtml : 
The html contains

```
TEST : false
```

But testValue is null in backing